# Linq C# based on max value

Tags: c#, linq, max

I fetch data from the database, which results in the following structure. Group by `InputFileId` and `Filename` and only select the maximum value of `Failed`.

```
InputFileId = 12, FileName = "Filename_12", Failed = false
InputFileId = 13, FileName = "Filename_13", Failed = false  
InputFileId = 13, FileName = "Filename_13", Failed = true
```

Now I only want to see this result :

```
InputFileId = 12, FileName = "Filename_12", Failed = false
InputFileId = 13, FileName = "Filename_13", Failed = true
```

The Linq query I have so far is:

```
Files = (this.InputFileStatusService.GetFilesUploadedByDay(StartOfDay(SelectedDate), EndOfDay(SelectedDate), this.Deal.Id))
            .Where(a => a.InputFileId > 0)
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.InputFileId, m.FileName, Failed = m.Failed ? 1 : 0 })
            .Select(m => new 
            { 
                InputFileId = m.Key.InputFileId, 
                FileName = m.Key.FileName,
                Failed = m.Max(x=>x.Failed) 
            }).ToList();
```

But this isn't working, does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: By "Select the Maximum value of Failed" you mean return True if any is true?

Comment: You want to group by `InputFileId`? But according to what you selected 'InputFileId = 13, FileName = "Filename_13", Failed = true' instead of `InputFileId = 13, FileName = "Filename_13", Failed = false`?

Comment: Yes, If there are multiple value for the same InputFileId and Filename, then I only want to show that the file is failed, so Failed should be true then.

Comment: Yes there should be FileName aswell in it.

Comment: @Walter, what if there is one value for `InputFileId` but the value of `Failed` field is `true`?

Comment: It should be taken as true, only if there are multiple values for the same InputFileId and FileName it should take true when there is a Failed value false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be enough to replace `Max` with `Any`

```
Failed = m.Any(x => x.Failed)
```

And remove the `Failed = m.Failed ? 1 : 0` in

```
.GroupBy(m => new { m.InputFileId, Failed = m.Failed ? 1 : 0 })
```

Since those columns seem to correspond to each other you might consider to add a grouping for `m.FileName` aswell.

Answer (score 4):

You are grouping by the `Failed` so in each group you will have 1 item - and the `Max(Failed)` of it will be the same as in the key.

Group only by the `InputFieldId` and check if `Any` in the group has a value of `true` for `Failed`:

```
Files = (this.InputFileStatusService.GetFilesUploadedByDay(StartOfDay(SelectedDate), EndOfDay(SelectedDate), this.Deal.Id))
            .Where(a => a.InputFileId > 0)
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.InputFileId, m.FileName })
            .Select(m => new 
            { 
                InputFileId = m.Key.InputFileId, 
                FileName = m.Key.FileName, 
                Failed = m.Any(x => x.Failed) 
            }).ToList();
```